# jboss hot deployment problems with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jboss, deployment

I have the following problem. When I deploy my ear file to server\default\deploy folder of JBOSS the first time, things seem to work fine.  But then, with JBOSS still running, if I delete and recopy the ear file again, my unit tests fail with the exception listed below. It's like it loses the Hibernate mappings for the entities during the hot deploy. Then, if I stop and restart JBOSS again without making a single change, things work again. So it's like the hot deploy isn't working right.

Have any of you experienced this problem or know of a workaround?

Thanks for any help.

Enviroment:
Windows XP SP3
JBoss 4.2.3GA
Hibernate 3.3.1
Hibernate Entity Manager 3.4.0

javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TestEntity is not mapped [FROM TestEntity]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:83)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:809)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:608)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:406)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TestEntity is not mapped [FROM TestEntity]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createQuery(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:134)
    at com.topcoder.test.TestBean.retrieveAll(TestBean.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:809)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:608)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:406)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:173)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:163)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy0.retrieveAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.topcoder.test.TestEntityTestCase.testFake(TestEntityTestCase.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy0.retrieveAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.topcoder.test.TestEntityTestCase.testFake(TestEntityTestCase.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TestEntity is not mapped [FROM TestEntity]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createQuery(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:134)
    at com.topcoder.test.TestBean.retrieveAll(TestBean.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:809)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:608)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:406)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:173)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have at the class?

> com.topcoder.test.TestBean.retrieveAll(TestBean.java:62)
>   at

Comment: List<TestEntity> result = em.createQuery("FROM TestEntity").getResultList();

Comment: Two ideas. Try to switch to criteria API or use full qualified name in HQL instead of "TestEntity".

Comment: The fully qualified name seems to help the problem. It no longer fails on that line. What do you think could be the reason for this behavior? Why is the fully qualified name not required on a cold deploy, but it *is* required on a hot deploy?

But, there's still a problem on hot deploy. If I modify any of the code in my TestBean class, I'll get an exception like this when trying to run:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause
 at 

Sorry I can't list all the trace, I ran out of characters allowed on the comment.

Comment: Well to be honest, I've no idea why full qualified name helps. I can guess that after hot deployment you will have two classes in your classpath. In my own experience with hot deployment (tomcat 5.5) it's more like a toy than ready for production/development using.